# Manga where a boy plays a virtual reality game and gets a dragon thats terrible but turns out to be good

Tags: dragon-drive

A manga where some boy is convinced to get in this pod where you randomly get a dragon selected for you and his is literally terrible. But it has hidden off the charts abilities? Any help? I gave it away years ago to a school and now can't remember the name of it for the life of me!

Comment: is it Dragon Drive?

Comment: can you remember the year you read it?

Answer (score 8):

I think this is really [Dragon Drive](http://myanimelist.net/manga/935/Dragon_Drive).

[image]

**Dragon Drive** is a manga by Kenishi Sakura which finished publishing in the **year 2006**.

> The story follows a boy named **Reiji Oozora** who's a total loser at school. One day, his friend takes to hidden place and forces him to play a **virtual game** called **Dragon Drive**. When he joins the game, he receives his own dragon. But the worst thing is that his **dragon is so small and weak that it can't possibly do anything** and so he names it [Chibi](http://doragondoraibu.wikia.com/wiki/Chibisuke).

As stated from the [wiki](http://doragondoraibu.wikia.com/wiki/Chibisuke):

> *As Chibi, he appears to be the weakest dragon, but in his true form, known as Senkoukura, he is the most powerful of all dragons, and worshipped as a deity by some.*

**Chibi in his original and weak form:**

> [image]

**Chibi in his true form, Senkoukura:**

> [image]